# How to filter only message in log file

Tags: shell-script

The example of log looks like this:

```
 01/13-21:25:26.314976  [**] [1:5000003:1] DoS Attack Detected [**] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 53.183.226.103:13968 -> 192.168.2.1:80
 01/13-21:30:56.771459  [**] [1:500000005:1] SSH Bruteforce Attack Detected [**] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 192.168.2.142:59878 -> 192.168.2.1:22
```

I would ask how to extract only the message which are DoS Attack Detected and SSH Bruteforce Attack Detected?

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested about the **attacks**, here is one way with awk.

```
   awk  '/Attack Detected/' logfile
```

Comment: If I want to use if else to read the file `while read INPUT_DATA
do
    if grep -q "DoS Attack Detected"; then
        echo "DoS"
    else
        echo "Other attacks"
    fi
done`     How to make this script echo differently?  What should I change "grep -q" to be?

Comment: if grep -q "Dos Attack Detected" INPUT_DATA; then echo "DoS"; elif grep -q "SSH Bruteforce Attack Detected"; then echo "SSH"; else echo "Other attacks"; fi

Comment: It does not work, for else case, it also echo "DoS". I think maybe the file contains both types of attack. How about other command?

Comment: Yes, It will catch all of the Attack if they are in the same logfile. My original awk solution stands, since you're just after the attacks.

Comment: I tried `if awk  '/DoS Attack Detected/' logfile`, it still print the whole log. Not echo "DoS"

Comment: What are you trying to do with the logs? Please explain.

Comment: The log file contains 2 types of attack. Which are DoS and SSH Bruteforce. I want to echo the word, for example if a line in file contains DoS, it will echo "DoS" and if a line represents other types of attack, it will echo "Other attacks".

Comment: while read -r line; do if [[ $line == `*DoS*` ]]; then echo "Line ${line%%:*} contains DoS Attack"; else echo "Line ${line%%:*} contains other Attacks"; fi; done < <(grep -n Attack logfile)

Comment: It has error like this:  [[: not found
Line 01/14-00 contains other Attacks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103287/discussion-between-jetchisel-and-jess-brown).